# How to select limited data per category

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table named Category like

```
Id    Name
1     A
2     B
```

And i have product table like

```
Id   Name    Category_id
1    C       1
2    D       1
3    E       1
4    F       2
5    G       2
6    H       2
```

I want to select 2 items from each category. I am applying this query

```
Select Product.id,Product.name as pname,category.name as cname from product join category where Category_id=Category.id limit 0,4
```

But it's returning first four data of the product table like

```
Product.id    Pname    Cname
1             C        A
2             D        A
3             E        A
4             F        B
```

But i Want to get 2 product from each category

```
Product.id    Pname    Cname
1             C        A
2             D        A
4             F        B
5             G        B
```

Comment: doesn't seem to have anything to do with PHP. I edited your tags. If you use accurate tags which relate more closely to your specific issue (rather than to, say, technology which you use elsewhere in your app but isn't relevant to this problem) then it's more likely that people with relevant skills will see your question and be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select p.id pid, name, p.name pname, c.name cname
from (
    select p.*, row_number() over(partition by category_id order by id) rn from product p
) p
inner join category c on c.id = p.category_id
where p.rn <= 2
```

Comment: Can we do this without subquery